# Forgot PGP Passphrase for Docker Login

Tags: docker-compose, pgp

I want to use Docker Desktop and to run docker-compose up, but I am getting permission denied and a prompt asking me to enter passphrase for PGP, but I forgot and don't even remember setting a passphrase in the first place.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIP65.png)

What to do? I don't care if I loose stuff, I just want to run Docker.

I tried to uninstall Docker and docker-compose and reinstalling, but the problem persists. How do I recover the passphrase?